# Is a nonnegative integrable extened real valued function always measureable?

Tags: measure-theory

Say you have measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and $f:X\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ such that it is nonnegative, integrable. Can one immediately conclude that $f$ is measurable?

Comment: Measurability is taken as a prerequisite to integrability. That is, we can only judge if a function is integrable or not if the function is first measurable.

Comment: Review the def'n of the integral with respect to a measure. It has no meaning for a non-measurable function.